# Verifying tokens in real-time to store in NgRx state?

Tags: angular, architecture, authorization, reactive-programming, ngrx

I have an "authenticated" boolean in my NgRx store keeping track of whether a user is valid or not.
But this variable can only be toggled when an action is taken -- logging in, logging out, or sending a POST, for instance -- because I have to verify it on my back-end as well as client-side. Therefor, it cannot be used the way I intend (as a reliable State variable in my Store). I want to know if there is a way to keep this boolean real-time?

Comment: Did you considered creating a custom selector that will select slices from the store and based on them, determine whether the user is authenticated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do like that: you have a store for the auth state that has this boolean value with the default value `undefined`, it means the state isn't clear and all guards and other pieces of the app should wait to the `boolean`.

When the app is loading you need to verify the auth state via issuing a request `/me` or `/ping` for example and based on its response you set the variable to true / false via related actions.

Also you should have an interceptor that knows if a request was declined due to expired / wrong auth state and this interceptor also sets the variable to true / false via related actions.